# How to code an "Add to Cart" at the end of each row that ONLY adds THAT item to cart?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm displaying a list of books on a table from my database, I want to add an 'Add to Cart' button at the end of each row. I'm having trouble finding out how can I distinguish each row so that the "Add to Cart" of row #2 only adds the book in row #2 to user's cart.

Something like this: [image]

This is the PHP for my search page:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
           $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['search']);
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%$search%' OR author LIKE '%$search%' OR rdate LIKE '%$search%'";
           $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
           $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
           if($queryResult > 0){
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                  echo "

                  <tr>
                  <td>".$row['title']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['author']."</td>
                  <td>".$row['rdate']."</td>
                  <td><a class='cartbtn' href='cart.php?id=".$_SESSION['username']."'>Add to Cart</a></td>
                  </tr>";
               }
           } else {
            echo "There are no results matching your search";
           }
        }
    ?>
```

Once the user clicks Add to Cart, I want to transfer him to a page "cart.php" where he can see all the items in his cart and maybe even be able to delete them, but that's for later - for now, I would really like some guidance on how I can indicate the "Add to Cart" button to only add the book that the user wants in his cart and not all of them. I apologize in advance if my question comes off as vague and not-so-transparent.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) the string is not safe!

Comment: Add the book information to the add to cart link.

Comment: Why are you currently appending `$_SESSION['username']` to those links? That makes very little sense … _Because_ you have this value in the session, you have access to it in the target script already, without sending it on a round-trip to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `books` table has a primary key column called `id` (if it isn't called that, replace the `id` in `$row['id']` below with whatever it's called)

```php
<td><a class='cartbtn' href='cart.php?id=".$_SESSION['username']."&book_id=".$row['id']."'>Add to Cart</a></td>
```

You can then get the `id` of the `book` in `cart.php`

```php
// Get the  ID of the book we're adding to the cart
$book_id = $_GET[ 'book_id' ];

// Code to add to cart here, e.g. 
$_SESSION[ 'cart_items' ][] = $book_id;
```

Comment: ````<td><a class='cartbtn' href='cart.php?id=".$_SESSION['username']."&book_id=".$row['id']."'>Add to Cart</a></td>````

With this, wouldn't the cart page we get redirected to, only display the one book we click? I was hoping for the user to add multiple books to cart and then be able to view them in cart.php in another table (like the one in picture)

Comment: Yes, it would redirect them to the cart page, as per your question: "_Once the user clicks Add to Cart, I want to transfer him to a page "cart.php"_"

Comment: If you want users to add multiple books, you will need javascript to add a "selected" class to the `<td>` (which could also be styled to highlight their selections) when the "Add to Cart" button is pressed - then another "Proceed To Cart" button which finds all `<td>` with the "selected" class and post their IDs to the server. You'd probably want something like `<td data-id='".$row['id']."'>` to achieve this.